# Access JSP page objects in EL tags

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a code like

```
<% int myvar =20; %>
```

I wish to access it via JSP tags, is something like this possible?

```
${pageScope.myvar}
```

Comment: What happened when you code like that? Are you getting any error? Why not give a simple try?

Comment: not able to get access to it, printing a blank value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scriptlet variables are created in *service* method and hence they have *local* scope so the

EL cannot evaluate them. The `EL` operates upon scoped variables - page scope, request,

session and application scope.

Comment: Also, if I declare it in the declartion block like <@! .. @>, they dont seem to be accessable!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
--<c:set var="myvar" scope="page" value = " value="${20}" />
<c:out  value = "${pageScope.str}"  /> ---
```

Try above code